# How can I point to Sqoop to use the TAB as a delimiter?

Tags: hadoop, char, sqoop, hadoop2

I'm trying to get data from Hadoop to MySQL. For this aim I'm using Sqoop.

On Hadoop (HDFS) side in output () I receive `key,value` separated by <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Now I would like to put the output to DB via Sqoop by:

```
sqoop-export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test 
         --username root --password pswd 
         --table counter 
         --export-dir /usr/local/hadoop/output
         --input-fields-terminated-by '***TAB***'
```

How can I point to Sqoop in `--input-fields-terminated-by` line to use the TAB as a delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
--input-fields-terminated-by "\t"
```